# Qt + OpenGL : how to properly override QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

It seems that `QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent` and `QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent` do unwanted `glClear`.

I don't want to clear the screen before every `paintGL` call, but Qt does it automatically, so i've overrided `QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent` like this:

```
void GlWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
   makeCurrent();
   paintGL();
   paintWithQPainter();
}
```

Seems that it works fine.

Then i've tried to override `QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent` (I don't need to call `glViewPort` right here):

```
void GlWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    // QWidget::resizeEvent(event); // i've also tried this, doesn't help
    resizeGL(event->size().width(), event->size().height());
}
```

When I resize the window, something goes wrong, for example: if I decrease window's height, the drawn text (it is drawn using `QPainter` after `paintGL`) has less height and the letters look like compressed, also antialiasing doesn't work properly. You can see it at the picture, look at the text, don't pay attention to colored area.

[image]

So I have 2 questions:

1) Although rendering (without resizing) works fine, do I miss some calls in the overrided `paintEvent`?

2) Which calls should I add into the overrided `resizeEvent`, which are called in the base class `resizeEvent`?

**UPD:** I've came up with a simple idea just to open qopenglwidget.cpp source and see how it works and fix it for my needs, I will try it someday.

Comment: resizeEvent is not the problem, the task of resizeEvent is to notify that the widget has changed and to call paintEvent, paintEvent must use the logic and create a suitable painting so if you do not show how you are painting we will be able to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added **UPD** for you.

Comment: what is `someRect`? please take the time and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc someRect is just a `QRect someRect (10, 10, 200, 50);`

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get with your update to show the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc i've added a new screenshot in the end after **UPD**

Comment: Why not point out that the height of the text is incorrect? What would be the right height and why?

Comment: @eyllanesc I've noticed that the text height became incorrect after i decrease window height, the text height is small. I've added two pictures.

Comment: Now the problem is clearer.

Comment: I just implemented what you point out and I do not see that the height of the text changes, so if you want help you should take the time and provide an [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to call original resizeEvent before or after your code.

```
void GlWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    //your code...
    QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's actually what I did not want to do, because I had mentioned that "_and QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent do unwanted glClear_". And that's why I want to override it. So, please, read questions more attentively :)


I've came up actually with a simple idea just to open qopenglwidget.cpp and see how It works and fix it for my needs, I will try it someday.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an answer on Qt Forum: https://forum.qt.io/topic/96016/how-to-properly-override-qopenglwidget-resizeevent

I was told that if I want to prevent `glClear` between `paintEvent` I need to call `QOpenGLWidget::setUpdateBehavior(QOpenGLWidget::PartialUpdate)`.

As for resizing - the resizing events are pretty rare, so it's better not to mess up `QOpenGLWidget` state by overriding it's `resizeEvent` (which recreates the internal FBO and sets a bunch of internal state) than try to prevent not significant `glClear` calls after resizing.

**UPD**: I've came up with a simple idea just to open qopenglwidget.cpp source and see how it works and fix it for my needs, I will try it someday.